# Error while crawling LOB contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search, crawling, crawl

I have configured and run sample code taken from the MSDN website for a custom BCS indexing connector sample for Sharepoint 2013:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-MyFileConne-79d2ea26

During it's intent to crawl, the crawler shows this error in the crawl log:

> myfile://servername/CustomConnectorTest Error while crawling LOB
>   contents. ( Error caused by exception:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path
>   '\servername\CustomConnectorTest\MyFileModel.xml' is denied. )

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error? I covered all of the obvious (fileshare/folder has the correct permissions, default content access account has the correct permissions, etc).

Answer (score 1):

"Error while crawling LOB contents" is permission related. As it seems to be a file share you want to crawl go to the file server and look at both permissions.

- Sharing permissions
- Security (NTFS) permissions

For testing purposes set both to "everyone" and "modify" and rerun your crawler. After validating success check the crawler service account user and set both permissions more strict for this user.

Comment: Oh  - seems to be a very old question. It popped up in my questions area and so I answered it. Sorry... Do not know why this old one came up now...

Answer (score 0):

The path to the model file is incorrect. It should be **\\**servername - aditionally check if the search account can access this share!