# Crawlers raises an error when crawling these URLs that end with a double Guid, what are they?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

What are the URLs that have this format in SharePoint 2016 on-premise? They seem to be automatically generated and the search crawler is raising an "Error while crawling LOB contents" when trying to crawl them.

https://intranet.*****.**/667b752d-d55f-4bfe-92fb-e54034e4ad2c/03052094-b4f8-4d76-bba7-449cea5e3b76

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in the URL are normal **GUIDs**. They can be site GUID, list GUID, item GUID, etc., based on the content you are crawling.

This is not enough information for troubleshooting. You can post the complete error message, especially the part `Error caused by exception` so that we can see where the problem lies.

See a similar post here: [Error while crawling LOB contents.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74566/error-while-crawling-lob-contents)

Another blog with similar error message here: [SharePoint Search – Error While Crawling LOB Contents.](https://prairiedeveloper.com/2016/04/sharepoint-search-error-crawling-lob-contents/)

Comment: Thank you @Chelsea_MSFT ! Well, the error looks generic, for all the 347 entries it is: `Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.; SearchID = B8C78193-0010-4694-85CC-C90C969D7DE0 )`. When I try to navigate to any one of the entries I get a `404 Page Not Found`. The Account that I use has "Full Permission" in an web application policy.

Comment: @CirodiMarzo Check out this blog for the same error (Error 2), see if it helps: 
https://joepaulk.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/search-crawl-error-log-error-while-crawling-lob-contents/